# css image links after minify with google tool

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, minify

i have problem with image links in css file, btw i use [google minify tool](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) if that can cause the problem ?

I use image in css like this:

```
background: url('../images/image.png');
```

and image doesn't show at website, because address is:

```
http://domain.com/domain.com/public/images/image.png
```

and the correct link should be:

```
http://domain.com/public/images/image.png
```

domain.com is folder at my hosting, so it adds that folder, how can i fix this ?

This is **.htaccess** code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    # Enable expirations
    ExpiresActive On

    # My favicon
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year”

    # Images
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 7 days"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 7 days"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 7 days"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 7 days"

    # CSS
    # ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 7 days"

    # Javascript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 7 days"
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution.
In /min/config.php add this line:

```
$min_serveOptions['rewriteCssUris'] = false;
```

Sorry.

Comment: You should add this to the main question, rather than posting it as an answer. Apart from that, your question is riddled with bad grammar to the point of being nearly illegible.